# Artery( Veins extension ) example is not working

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, sumo

I do not have much experience with Omnet,I would like to know if I correctly running the command to run the example.

First when I type make Vanetza, I realized that COHDA_MK2_ROOT is missing, however, the Vanetza compiles without error:

`mkdir extern/vanetza/build 
cd extern/vanetza/build && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   serialization
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
-- Found GeographicLib: /usr/local/include (found suitable version "1.46", minimum required is "1.37") 
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
-- Found CryptoPP: /usr/include (found suitable version "5.6.1", minimum required is "5.6.1") 
**-- Could NOT find Cohda (missing:  COHDA_MK2_ROOT)** 
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done`

When I try to run the `./run` command with root into the /artery/scenarios/artery, it returns:

```
./run: 2: ./run: ../../run: not found
```

When I try to run the `opp_run` command into the same folder, I can open the Omnet, however, the simulation does not run since the Scenario.ned is missing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those run scripts are obsolete by now. You can run simulations through the new run targets, i.e. the scenario from the `scenarios/artery` folder can be executed by the `run_example` target in your build directory.

If you have followed the build instructions in Artery's README then it looks like this:

```
cd build
make run_example
```

You can also start the simulation environment trough the `debug_example`target if you have built with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE set to "Debug",

PS: "Could NOT find Cohda (missing: COHDA_MK2_ROOT)" is not a severe error at all, it just informs about a build configuration without features requiring this optional dependency.

Comment: I ran the command `make run_example` and an error occurred. SUMO stopped and the log shows that the file "extern/veins/examples/veins/erlangen.net.xml" did not exist, to solve this problem I copied the .net.xml, rou.xml, poly.xml and sumo.cfg from Veins example folder to scenarios/artery. After that, I removed the line <basedir path = "extern/veins/example/veins" /> from launchd.xml file. It's working fine. Thank you Raphael!

Comment: Veins' sumo-launchd.py script is sensitive to the directory where it was started. I recommend to invoke this script through `make launch_sumo` for Artery. Then you should not need to copy any files around.